# MonoDroid: Unhandled Exception Recovery

Tags: c#, android, exception, mono, xamarin.android

I'm trying to add a default handler to my application so I can recover from otherwise unhandled exceptions.

I've found three mechanisms provided by Android/MonoDroid that, as far as I can tell, should make this possible, but I cannot get any of them to work. Here's my code:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace TestApp {
    [Android.App.Activity(Label = "TestApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(new LinearLayout(this));

            //set up handlers for uncaught exceptions:
            //Java solution
            Java.Lang.Thread.DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler = new ExceptionHandler(this);
            //MonoDroid solution #1
            AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += AndroidEnvironment_UnhandledExceptionRaiser;
            //MonoDroid solution #2
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += delegate { new Alert(this, "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException", "error"); };

            //throw an exception to test
            throw new Exception("uncaught exception");
        }

        void AndroidEnvironment_UnhandledExceptionRaiser(object sender, RaiseThrowableEventArgs e)
        {
            //found a suggestion to set the Handled flag=true, but it has no effect
            new Android.Runtime.RaiseThrowableEventArgs(e.Exception).Handled = true;
            new Alert(this, "AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser", "error");
        }
    }

    public class ExceptionHandler : Java.Lang.Object, Java.Lang.Thread.IUncaughtExceptionHandler {
        private Context _context;
        public ExceptionHandler(Context c) { _context = c; }
        public void UncaughtException(Java.Lang.Thread thread, Java.Lang.Throwable ex) {
            new Alert(_context, "java exception handler");
        }
    }

    public class Alert {
        public Alert(Context c, string src, string title = "alert") {
            Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(c);
            builder.SetTitle(title);
            builder.SetMessage(src);
            builder.SetPositiveButton("Ok", delegate { });
            Android.App.AlertDialog alert = builder.Create();
            alert.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm seeing similar issues when not debugging my application.  I can tell you that the `AndroidEnvironment` gets called and handles uncaught exceptions before the `AppDomain` does.

Comment: That's not the way "to set the Handled flag=true", it should be `e.Handled = true;`... :-B

Answer (score -1):

You can catch most of exceptions in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event. But you can't call AlertDialog in this delegate, because:
1. Application is crashed. 
2. UnhandledException event is called at least.
3. alert.Show() is executed async (in UI thread)

So, you should use sync operations (System.IO, for example). You shouldn't use native UI operations, because they are async.